# Render label using itextsharp to pdf and word

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise

```
Could not load file or assembly 'itextsharp, Version=5.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8354ae6d2174ddca' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have added reference to ItextSharp 5.4. and got this error.

I have a dropdown created when selected that render as pdf or word.

```
  {
            string sDirPath = Server.MapPath("~/PDF_WORD/Docs");
            var ObjSearchDir = new DirectoryInfo(sDirPath);
            if (!ObjSearchDir.Exists)
            {
                ObjSearchDir.Create();
            }
            string strFileName =
                HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/PDF_WORD/Docs/Test." + DropDownListDownloadCv0.SelectedValue.ToString() +
                                                   "");
            var objfileinfo = new FileInfo(strFileName);
            // step 1: creation of a document-object
            var document = new Document();


            if (objfileinfo.Exists)
            {
                File.Delete(strFileName);
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(strFileName, FileMode.Create));
            }
            else
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(strFileName, FileMode.Create));
            // step 2:
            // we create a writer that listens to the document
            //StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder();
            var sw = new StringWriter();

            document.Open();
            var hTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);



            lblphonenumber.RenderControl(hTextWriter);
            String strHtml1 = sw.ToString();


            var styles = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet();
            var hw = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(document);
            hw.Parse(new StringReader(strHtml1));

            document.Close();

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you add the Itextsharp dll to the global assembly cache (GAC) on your server.

For 2010 the GAC is found under

```
C:\Windows\assembly
```

For 2013

```
C:\windows\microsoft.net\assembly\GAC_MSIL
```

(But to add an DLL for 2013, please follow [the instructions on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79.aspx), you can not just drag and drop as in 2010)

Comment: were do i find the global assembly cache (GAC)

Comment: Ammended my answer

Comment: Please mark this as an answer if it helped you out